# Application context and spring context is same?

Tags: spring, web-applications, applicationcontext

I am new to spring MVC,and just started working on it.I would like to know about the application context(web-applicationcontext) and the context provided by the spring i.e spring-servlet.xml whether it is same or different.

Hopefully somebody could give me the greater idea to come over this confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between the application context and servlet context is that whatever is specified in the application context can be referenced in the servlet context, but not vice-versa.

That's to say that you can have components that are reused through your servlets specified at the application context level, but certain things that are only specific to a certain servlet can be specified there to isolate them from the application and other servlets.

That's there if you have a need for fine-grained control.

Comment: thanks filip,so if i create the mapping at the application level(inside the applicationContext file) is accessible inside the servlet context as well ?

Comment: Yes, for things like models, which you'd possibly want all servlets to have access to, you would specify them in the application context. As an example, if you specify a controller in a certain servlet context, you won't be able to resolve controllers located in other servlet contexts, at least not as directly and easily. If you do so, you don't risk resolution clashing or polluting your context with components that shouldn't be a part of it. But this is all really when and if you need fine-grained control--most applications out there don't even have more than one servlet context.

Answer (score 0):

You can treat them as being the same file. Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495247/spring-using-applicationcontext-xml-and-xxxxx-servlet-xml) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The application-context provided by *-servlet.xml is the WebApplicationContext see [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) for more info on this. The root application is created by the contextLoader listener .

Quoting from the Spring reference,

"In the web MVC framework, each DispatcherServlet has its own WebApplicationContext, which   inherits all the beans already defined in the root WebApplicationContext.

The WebApplicationContext is an extension of the plain ApplicationContext that has some extra features necessary for web applications. It differs from a normal ApplicationContext in that it is capable of resolving themes (see Section 15.7, “Using themes”), and that it knows which servlet it is associated with (by having a link to the ServletContext). The WebApplicationContext is bound in the ServletContext, and by using static methods on the RequestContextUtils class you can always look up the WebApplicationContext if you need access to it."

You can find the details of the root Application context [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-introduction)